# Wine won't find HID USB device (Power Commander V interface)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, wine, usb-hid

I am trying to get [Dynojet Power Commander V](https://www.dynojet.com/dynojet-motorcycle-power-commander/) (PCV) software functioning in Wine 4.0 and 18.2x64. The program starts fine, but it cannot find the controller which is connected via USB as a HID.  It works in [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) (Windows 7), but that is bulky for what I'm trying to do.

I entered the registry key in https://wiki.winehq.org/Hid and many other things that didn't work.  The Wine debug log just says it couldn't find the controller, nothing useful.  There is no option in the PCV software that directs the connection.

It just uses the generic Windows HID driver.

```
$ dmesg

[17133.472348] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[17133.622299] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=10b6, idProduct=0502
[17133.622303] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[17133.622306] usb 3-3: Product: Power Commander 5
[17133.622308] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Dynojet Research, Inc.
[17133.623766] hid-generic 0003:10B6:0502.0006: hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v2.00 Device [Dynojet Research, Inc. Power Commander 5] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0

$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1770:ff00

$ sudo lsusb -v -d 10b6:0502

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 10b6:0502
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x10b6
  idProduct          0x0502
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 Dynojet Research, Inc.
  iProduct                2 Power Commander 5
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               2.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      37
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I entered the registry key in https://wiki.winehq.org/Hid"*?